# Spring @Value without annotation

Tags: java, spring

Instead of using `@Value` doing this:

```
@Service
public class MyService{
    @Value("${myValue}")
    private String myValue;
}
```

I need to get `${myValue}` without annotation, and without reading the file again. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from `Environment`:

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;
// ... 
env.getProperty("myValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to access `Environment` is through [`EnvironmentAware`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/EnvironmentAware.html) interface.

Example :

```
@Service
public class MyService implements EnvironmentAware{

    private String myValue;
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.env = environment;
    }

    public String getMyValue() {
        return env.getProperty("myValue");
    }
}
```